# Gaussian random matrix rotation invariance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, orthogonality, variance

Checking exercise 3.3.3 from [R. Vershynin](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)

Let G be an m × n Gaussian random matrix, i.e. the entries of G are
independent N(0, 1) random variables. Let u ∈ Rn be a fixed unit vector.
Then Gu ∼ N(0, Im)

I went about it by multiplying Matrix G by vector u which ends up with a vector of dimension mx1 of the entries
$$
\begin{matrix}
<G11,u1> & +\cdots+ & <G1n, un> \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
<Gm1,u1> & +\cdots+ & <Gmn, un> \\
\end{matrix}
$$

I can show that the vector Gu has an Expected value of zero since Gij ∼ N(0, 1) and uj is a constant. However, I'm struggling to show that the variance of Gu is the Identity matrix of dimension m. Since I end up with the variance of the sum of the variances of Gi in each row multiplied by the squared sum of uj. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Your questions will get more attention if you typset them properly. You should check out this guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $(Gu)_{i}=\sum_{j}G_{ij}u_{j}$.
Denoting by $\delta_{ij}$ the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), we have
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Gu)_{i}(Gu)_{i^{\prime}}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j}G_{ij}u_{j}\right)\left(\sum_{j}G_{i^{\prime}j}u_{j}\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{jj^{\prime}}G_{ij}G_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}u_{j}u_{j^{\prime}}\right]\\
=\sum_{jj^{\prime}}\mathbb{E}\left[G_{ij}G_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}\right]u_{j}u_{j^{\prime}}=\sum_{jj^{\prime}}\delta_{ii^{\prime}}\delta_{jj^{\prime}}u_{j}u_{j^{\prime}}=\delta_{ii^{\prime}}\sum_{j}u_{j}^{2}=\delta_{ii^{\prime}}\Vert u\Vert^{2}=\delta_{ii^{\prime}}
\end{multline*}
as desired.